# get all image source from a website in php

Tags: php, image, domdocument, fopen, src

What I want to do is let the user type a url which has images such as https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=arushad%20ahmed , and get all the image source in the 'src' attribute and display it.

The following approach didn't work:

```
$file = fopen("https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=arushad%20ahmed", "r");
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($file);
$image = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($image as $img) {
    echo $img;
}
```

So how can I make this work as I want?

Comment: src isn't a tag, it's an attribute.

Comment: I know I just started using php.

Comment: Did you manage to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src` isn't a `tag`, it's an `attribute`.
You said you're new to php so that's pretty normal, now worries, use this code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=arushad%20ahmed");
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$imgs = $xpath->query("//img");
for ($i=0; $i < $imgs->length; $i++) {
    $img = $imgs->item($i);
    $src = $img->getAttribute("src");
    // do something with $src
}
```

---

Learn more about [PHP DOMDocument](http://www.binarytides.com/php-tutorial-parsing-html-with-domdocument/)

---

## Update

Based on your comment, you don't seem to have PHP DOMDocument support, you can use the commands below to install it.

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=webtatic install php-xml
sudo /sbin/service httpd stop
sudo /sbin/service httpd start
```

Also, the page you're trying to parse doesn't contain valid HTML, use [HTML Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) to fix it, i.e.:

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=arushad%20ahmed');
$config = array(
  'clean' => 'yes',
  'output-html' => 'yes',
);
$tidy = tidy_parse_string($html, $config, 'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($tidy); 
//the rest of the code is the same
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$imgs = $xpath->query("//img");
for ($i=0; $i < $imgs->length; $i++) {
    $img = $imgs->item($i);
    $src = $img->getAttribute("src");
    // do something with $src
}
```

Comment: I guess the code would work if my php installation was correct. Getting  Error: Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Unable to find the wrapper &quot;https&quot; - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?